# Database open failed while useing notes API

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I am using a java application to control my notes client to send email.
some code:

```
session = NotesFactory.createSession();
db = session.getDatabase("mail01/xxx", "aaa.nsf");
```

"mail01/xxx" is remote server name.
the code is right? I am not sure.

but I got error:

```
NotesException: Database open failed (%1)
    at lotus.domino.local.Database.Nopen(Native Method)
    at lotus.domino.local.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at test.TestLocal.runNotes(TestLocal.java:67)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have configured path and classpath. And I have installed notes client on my computer.

This is my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Is the Lotus Notes client configured? can you access mail01/xxx form the Notes client?

Comment: Yes，I can send email by the notes client successfully.

Comment: That was not exactly my question: Can you open the database "aaa.nsf" using the File- Open- dialog in the client? If it is the mailfile on the server, then the path would be "mail\aaa.nsf", that's why I ask...

Comment: I got a window with title named "open application". The default database is names.nsf on my computer. Then I change to mail01/xxx, the default database is not aaa.nsf.

Comment: Change "Local" or "On my Computer" to "mail01/xxx" and press enter, then try to open "aaa.nsf" Does it work? Or do you have to switch to directory "mail" before opening aaa?

Comment: I have to switch to directory "mail" before opening aaa.nsf. And I get "no accesss" while opening aaa.nsf. So, I should code: `db = session.getDatabase("mail01/xxx", "mail/aaa.nsf")` right? Another question, how to control access? Thanks.

Comment: The database mail\aaa.nsf has an Access Control List (aka "ACL"). If you have "no access", then somebody who has Manager level access (typically the Domino administrators) must give you access.  Note, however, that this new information conflicts with what you said earlier -- that you can send emial with the Notes client.  If that is true, then you must have been accessing some mail database to do that, so apparently aaa.nsf is not the correct database.

Comment: sorry, I have access. I click another database earlier.Now I get database, but it's not opened. While invoking  `database.open();`, I got `NotesException: Database open failed (%1)
 at lotus.domino.local.Database.Nopen(Native Method)
 at lotus.domino.local.Database.open(Unknown Source)
 at test.TestLocal.runNotes(TestLocal.java:75)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: How do you run your code? Do you get password prompt for your ID?

Comment: I have solved it. I changed to `createSession((String) null, (String) null, password)`

Comment: @Jerry So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and how and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Find your notes.ini file on your computer.  Look for two lines:

```
MailServer=CN=mail01/O=xxx
MailFile=mail\aaa.nsf
```

These are the values that you need in arguments for the `getDatabase()` method. Note that you should double the backslashes in Java because the language will treat them as escapes, or just change them to forward slashes --the Notes API works with either format. You also do not need the 'CN=' and 'O=' as the Notes APIs will assume them if you omit them. But everything else should match exactly what you find in the notes.ini.

Better yet, instead of hard-coding the server and file, use the following code to read the values from notes.ini:

```
String mailServer = session.getEnvironmentString("MailServer",true);
String mailFile = session.getEnvironmentString("MailFile",true);
db = session.getDatabase(mailServer,mailFile);
```

If you do this, you don't have to worry about doubling backslashes or anything else. It will just work, as long as the client is configured correctly and the server and mailfile are accessible on the network. It should also work if your Notes client is configured to work with a local replica of the mail file.

Comment: I changed my code and got right database. But it was not opened.       `db.open(); `                                           `NotesException: Database open failed (%1)
 at lotus.domino.local.Database.Nopen(Native Method)
 at lotus.domino.local.Database.open(Unknown Source)
 at test.TestLocal.runNotes(TestLocal.java:77)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Is your call to NotesFactory.CreateSession() resulting in a dialog box requesting the password for your Notes user id? I.e., the same use id that you are using with your Notes client?

Comment: Yes， I input password, then enter. nothing happened.

Comment: I am actually using the Lotus Notes COM with .NET, but it was the same parameter problem. I opened my notes.ini file and found a string with slashes in it and used that as the server rather than a fully qualified domain name, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I need more reputation points to create a comment (*hint, hint*).

When debugging a problem like this it can be helpful to look at the error code in the NotesException object.  Assuming you are catching NotesException, what is the value of the public `NotesException.id` field?  That should map to one of the constants in the NotesError class (e.g. `NotesError.NOTES_ERR_DBNOACCESS`).

Also, your original question only shows 5 lines of the stack trace.  The root cause of the exception may be further down.  Can you include more of the stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the db ist not found. So try to change the path from the db. if your db is in a folder on the server give the path for the folder in java. Your path variable must have the right format.
In your case for Example it must be
session = NotesFactory.createSession();
db = session.getDatabase("mail01/xxx", "pathToDB/aaa.nsf");